# java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found?

Tags: java, resources, lwjgl, runtimeexception, slick2d

I can't understand why I'm getting this error: ***java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found*** I'm trying to make a simple 2d game using Slick and LWJGL libraries, I followed this guide http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLaNw_AbDFccGkU5gnFYquQ0PNQPmmD-Q7 and I managed to make even some more by myself.

The thing is that I am receiving this error even though the image does exist in the specified location. The game runs completely fine and suddenly quits with the error I already mentioned.

The error:

```
Wed Nov 27 14:43:46 PST 2013 ERROR:Resource not found:
/home/tomtam/workspace/Game/gfx/world/object/blockgreen.png
java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found:
/home/tomtam/workspace/Game/gfx/world/object/blockgreen.png
    at org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(ResourceLoader.java:69)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:273)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:270)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:244)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:232)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:198)
    at tomtam.game.object.BlockGreen.render(BlockGreen.java:18)
    at tomtam.game.main.World.render(World.java:447)
    at tomtam.game.state.PlayState.render(PlayState.java:76)
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.render(StateBasedGame.java:207)
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:703)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:456)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:361)
    at tomtam.game.main.Main.main(Main.java:36)
Wed Nov 27 14:43:46 PST 2013 ERROR:Game.render() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.render() failure - check the game code.
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:706)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:456)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:361)
    at tomtam.game.main.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

So the error points to this part of the code (image):

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException
{
    super.render(gc, g);
    image = new Image("/home/tomtam/workspace/Game/gfx/world/object/blockgreen.png");
}
```

I am not a skilled programmer, but I guess that this error is because the image is getting rendered nonstop, even if it's location or other information haven't changed. That may produce some lag spikes, right..? So, I tried to change it to:

```
try 
{ 
    image = new Image("/home/tomtam/workspace/Game/gfx/world/object/blockgreen.png"); 
} 
catch (RuntimeException npe) 
{ 
}
```

I know that it's a bad thing to do it like this, however, this way I am not receiving any errors and everything works fine for some time. After some time some images starts blinking and the more I wait, the less time they are showing up until finally disappearing.

The code is kinda long, but I can post it, just ask. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a      "java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found" occurs when your resources (images now) are not in your CLASSPATH and generally it is a classpath issue.

[This](http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6092) may also help you.

Comment: Thanks, but apparently it didn't work. I moved all the images to res, changed everywhere in .java files, but no luck.